# File Storage Plugin (For Individual Users)?

Tags: plugins

I have a client who has a Wordpress blog and he'd like to give a small number of clients their own user accounts in which, ideally, they'll be able to access a specific set of files. These files would only be visible to users to whom the files are assigned by the site administrator (for lack of a better word), not all users.

In other words, if Bob and Susan both had Wordpress accounts on this site, the site admin would be able to upload a file and assign it to Bob and that Susan would not be able to see. Bob and Susan wouldn't need to add files, just have access to files provided by the site admin.

I've Google'd around a bit for a plugin that will allow this, but I'm not finding anything. Does such a plugin exist?

Answer (score 2):

Hi **@inkedmn**:

What you are looking for **sounds taylor-made for [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)** as a hosted file service to complement your client's web hosting. It's incredibly cheap *(my S3 bill is currently US$0.01 per month, but only for a few files)* and has all sorts of content protection features like special expiring URLs and so on.

I wasn't able to find a plugin to do exactly what you are looking for, but you might be able to cobble something together from the features of several of these many Amazon S3 plugins:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amazon-s3-url-generator/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-s3/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tantan-s3/
- http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-s3/
- http://www.blogperfume.com/plugin-automatic-wordpress-backup-to-amazon-s3/
- http://www.wizardstower.co.uk/wordpress/2008/10/25/amazon-s3-plugin-for-wordpress/
- http://photocritic.org/wordpress-amazon-s3-cdn-plug-in/
- http://imthi.com/wp-s3
- http://tantannoodles.com/toolkit/wordpress-s3/

You also might be able to integrated with **WP-File Manager** *(or even just use it):*

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filemanager/

It actually sounds like a super-fun project; I'm jealous. I need to get one of my client to need something integrated with Amazon S3! :-) Good luck!

-Mike

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really rather late but maybe it will help someone - This is a great plugin that sounds like what you need

http://www.ajaxplorer.info/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how easy this would be in vanilla  WP.

By description it seems similar to [Group Documents](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-group-documents/) plugin for BuddyPress.