# Wordpress remote file storage

Tags: cdn, amazon

I am in pretty much the same position as the author of [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/file-storage-plugin-for-individual-users). I understand my post is something of a duplicate but the link is a few  years old and I wonder if the situation has changed any?

I have a client who runs (and loves) a WordPress website and uses Dropbox for sharing files with their clients (typically digital copies of contracts & machine manuals). They don't like using Dropbox as its not integrated with the website and isn't branded. I had hoped there was a Dropbox API that allowed for user/group based access to folders but there doesn't seem to be.

Are there any plugins/services out there that fit the bill or is the only option still to use Amazon S3?

Comment: There is a [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), and you can use it. BackWPup offers it as backup destination, so you can use it in plugins too. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic per the [faq], if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @toscho as far as I could gather the Dropbox API only allows for public access (it isn't possible to restrict by user or group permissions). Please correct me if I'm wrong as sticking with Dropbox would be ideal.@s_ha_dum I'm not looking for plugin recommendations, just if there are such plugins or remote storage providers with an API that integrates easily with WordPress

Comment: You can access the Dropbox per HTTP, that doesn't require any WordPress specifics. Have you searched in [dropbox-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropbox-api) and [dropbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropbox) on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I believe DropBox will only expose a file if you create a link to it. Then you can share link A with client A and link B with client B. How exactly do you see DropBox restricting file access by user? By creating a separate DropBox account for each? That's not integration, that's a nightmare.