# File Storage and Repository for individual user

Tags: plugins

I have a client who has a Wordpress blog and he'd like to give a small number of clients their own user accounts in which they'll be able to access a specific set of files.
These files would only be visible/downloadable to users to whom the files are assigned by the site administrator, not all users.

In example, if Bob and Susan both had Wordpress accounts on this site, the site owner would be able to upload a file and assign it to Bob and that Susan would not be able to see. Bob and Susan wouldn't need to add files, just have access to files provided by the site admin.

I've Google'd around a bit for a plugin that will allow this, but I'm not finding anything. Does such a plugin exist?

Similar question of that: [File Storage Plugin (For Individual Users)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/file-storage-plugin-for-individual-users) but that it's over 10 years old.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! You might try looking at the various membership plugins to see if any may work for your case. Plugin recommendations are off-topic here, so if you start custom coding and get stuck feel free to pop back in and ask for more specific assistance, or you may want to look into other resources if you need something more off-the-shelf.

Comment: For me solving this is very dependant on how much this will grow - how many users could there be later? Will they end up being arranged in groups? How many files will there be, will they be arranged in folders later? I feel like the right solution here is e.g. OwnCloud or Google Drive, and do the leg work of keeping users in sync between the two services, otherwise you might end up administering something that gets messy and out of control if you hobble it together in Wordpress.